How can I show the source for each completion in the nvim-cmp popup?
When an nvim-cmp popup show there is no indication of what source actually provided the completion nvim_lsp, luasnip, buffer, path, copilot, codeium, etc.

Is there any way to include the source name in the nvim-cmp floating window / menu?

Yes, via nvim_cmp configuration formatting.format like so
local cmp = require("cmp")
cmp.setup({
  formatting = {
    format = function(entry, vim_item)
      vim_item.menu = entry.source.name
      return vim_item
    end,
  }, -- formatting
  -- rest of configuration for nvim-cmp
})


If you want to combine with other formatting functions like lspkind (which adds symbols ) you can:
local lspkind = require("lspkind")
local lspkind = require("lspkind")
local lspkind_cmp_format = lspkind.cmp_format({})

cmp.setup({
  formatting = {
    format = function(entry, vim_item)
      vim_item.menu = entry.source.name
      kreturn lspkind.cmp_format({})(entry, vim_item)
    end,
  }, -- formatting
  -- rest of configuration for nvim-cmp
})


